# Can I specify key decisions for non-imported characters?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Like creating a "fresh" character in ME2, starting a non-imported character in ME3 has pre-defined decisions for the previous games already made for you. However, is there any other way to get around this? Is there any DLC available that's similar to the Genesis comic for ME2 on the PS3 that I can use to change the back story/decisions of my character?

Comment: I doubt it, without using a save editor, but I have no proof or anything so I'm not going to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 'official' way to do this. The game gives you the ability to make a few key choices at character creation (Specifically, you can name the Virmire survivor, or claim that you've experienced "numerous" losses, which results in a large number of otherwise surviving characters dying.)

As an unofficial option, you can grab a save file that fits your criteria from [MassEffect2Saves](http://www.masseffect2saves.com/), and/or use a saved game editor before importing.

Comment: You alluded to it, but I wanted to mention specifically the [Gibbed Save Game Editor](http://www.masseffectsaves.com/tools.php) as a way to tweak your saved games.